# In Blood Bowl Team Manager, are Freebooter Stars supposed to be more or less powerful than their regular counterparts?

Tags: blood-bowl-team-manager

According to the description in the [Rulesbook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/63/3c/633c1f5d-b979-4a88-81a7-f92ca9758959/bbtm_rulebook_english_web.pdf):

> Star Player Cards:
>
> These skilled players really know their way
>   around the pitch! These improvements include
>   famous Star Players and up-and-coming
>   freebooters – aspiring stars who haven’t quite
>   made it yet.

it seems to me that a freebooter is less powerful than a regular star, however, the effect of the mechanism used to recruit the Stars:

> If a manager drafts a Star Player with the Freebooter ability, the manager
>   searches his roster and chooses one player to return to the game box. Then he
>   adds the Star Player with the Freebooter ability to his roster and shuffles
>   it to create a new Team deck (see below for a full explanation of the Freebooter ability).
>   If the manager drafts any Star Players without the Freebooter ability, he
>   places them on top of his Team deck in any order.

leaves me with the impression than my roster is better improved when I recruit a Freebooter than a regular Star. Granted, the regular Star goes on top of the Deck, making sure that he will play the next game but on the other hand, the Freebooter allows you to remove a weak player from your deck and to shuffle your discard (potentially containing Stars) back into your deck.

So let's consider two Stars with the exact same abilities, is it better to recruit the Freebooter or the Regular Star?
What's the rationale behind this shuffling the discard back in the deck in this case?

> Freebooter: When you reveal this player from your improvement pile,
>   you may remove any one Player card from either your Team deck or discard
>   pile and return it to the game box. Then add the Freebooter to your roster
>   and shuffle it to create a new Team deck. Resolve all Freebooters before
>   placing Star Players without the Freebooter ability on top of the Team
>   deck. (Unlike other abilities, the Freebooter ability only occurs during
>   the turn in which this player was drafted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a big difference when you gain the star player.  Gaining the average freebooter in the first round is better than gaining the average non-freebooter (there are always specific exceptions of course) because you will get to use that player statistically more often due to the smaller deck size.  Conversely, gaining a freebooter in the fourth round is potentially useless, as you want any star players you gain to come into play in the last round; only the ones put on top of your deck are guaranteed to do this.  The tipping point is somewhere in between.

One other consideration is how much sprinting your base deck has.  Decks with more sprinting have less use for freebooters because they can filter their deck mid-game.  Consequently, it is better to have more powerful characters to get the most value out of the sprinting ability.

Answer (score 0):

With the Freebooter you not only gain a good (or at least decent) card, but  you also get rid of your least useful card.

With any deck-building game I have played through the years, one of the general principles was always the same: The smaller the deck, the better.